# presentViewController from sharedInstance of utility class

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, presentviewcontroller

I would like to present an MFMailComposerViewController from some code that resides deep within in a utilities class accessible via a shared instance.

When I try it with

```
[self presentViewController:mailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I get an error, that presenting view is not in the view hierarchy which makes sense.

When I try using the navigationController:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:mailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

no error occurs but nothing happens.

It makes sense that I should present it from the VC that calls the sharedInstance but I don't know how to reference that from within the shared instance.

Thanks for any suggestions on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can present it from the most top view controller. Here is what I did to get one.

```
+ (UIViewController *)topViewController {
    UIViewController *topController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows firstObject].rootViewController;

    if ([topController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        topController = [[(UINavigationController *)topController viewControllers] lastObject];
    }

    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;

        if ([topController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
            topController = [[(UINavigationController *)topController viewControllers] lastObject];
        }
    }

    return topController;
}
```